# spacy-udpipe with pytextrank to extract keywords from non-English text

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, udpipe, pytextrank

I've been using pytextrank (https://github.com/DerwenAI/pytextrank/) with spacy and English models for keywords extraction - it works great!

Now I need to process non-English texts and I found udpipe (https://github.com/TakeLab/spacy-udpipe) but it doesn't work out of the box ... after

```
nlp = spacy_udpipe.load("sk")
tr = pytextrank.TextRank()
nlp.add_pipe(tr.PipelineComponent, name="textrank", last=True)
doc = nlp(text)
```

I get tokens with POS and DEP tags, but there is nothing in `doc._.phrases` (`doc.noun_chunks` is also empty) and in `nlp.pipe_names` is just ['textrank']

What should I add to the spacy's pipeline to get it working? I assume pytextrank needs noun_chunks...

Any tip or suggestion where to look will help me - thanks!

Comment: how to implement the spacy pytextrank in pandas. I am getting 'TypeError: Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got Series)'. Can you share some sample? t = []
for i in nlp(dn['Review_Train']):
    if review._.phrases:
        t.append(review.text)

Comment: @RVKNLP that's a very different question, unrelated to UDpipe.  Could you please post is as an issue on https://github.com/DerwenAI/pytextrank/issues along with the code + data + exception trace ?  Definitely, `spaCy` and `pytextrank` can be used with `pandas` but the error you're describing seems to be more about the shape of your input for the dataframe

Answer (score 1):

would you mind starting an issue about this on the PyTextRank repo?
https://github.com/DerwenAI/pytextrank/issues

Also, if you could please provide example text to use (in the language requested)

We'll try to debug this integration.

Thanks for pointing it out!

Paco

Comment: Thanks for reply - meanwhile I realized, that it's more a problem with udpipe-spacy which somehow "overrides" the original spacy's pipeline so the noun_chunks are not generated (btw the noun_chunks are created in `lang/en/syntax_iterators.py` but it doesn't exist for all languages so even if it is called, it doesn't work e.g. for Slovak) ... I'll add you an issue in pytextrank, because I think it could be a good enhancement to to load the "noun_chunks" for example from a custom extension which uses a Matcher)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution! I'm not sure how clean is the `nlp.Defaults.syntax_iterators = {"noun_chunks" : get_chunks}`, but it works (it's based on how are the noun_chunks defined in `syntax_iterators.py` and `__init__.py` in `spaCy/lang/en`)

```
import spacy_udpipe, spacy, pytextrank
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
from spacy.attrs import POS

def get_chunks(doc):
    np_label = doc.vocab.strings.add("NP")
    matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
    pattern = [{POS: 'ADJ', "OP": "+"}, {POS: {"IN": ["NOUN", "PROPN"]}, "OP": "+"}]
    matcher.add("Adjective(s), (p)noun", None, pattern)
    matches = matcher(doc)

    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        yield start, end, np_label

spacy_udpipe.download("sk") # download model
nlp = spacy_udpipe.load("sk")
nlp.Defaults.syntax_iterators = {"noun_chunks" : get_chunks}  #noun_chunk replacement

tr = pytextrank.TextRank(logger=None)
nlp.add_pipe(tr.PipelineComponent, name="textrank", last=True)

text = "Wikipédia je webová encyklopédia s otvoreným obsahom, ktorú možno slobodne čítať aj upravovať. Je sponzorovaná neziskovou organizáciou Wikimedia Foundation. Má 285 nezávislých jazykových vydaní vrátane slovenského a najrozsiahlejšieho anglického. Popri článkoch encyklopedického typu obsahuje, najmä anglická encyklopédia, aj články podobajúce sa almanachu, atlasu či stránky aktuálnych udalostí. Wikipédia je jedným z najpopulárnejších zdrojov informácií na webe s približne 13 miliardami zobrazení mesačne. Jej rast je skoro exponenciálny. Wikipédii (takmer 2 milióny). Wikipédia bola spustená 15. januára 2001 ako doplnok k expertmi písanej Nupedii. So stále rastúcou popularitou sa Wikipédia stala podhubím pre sesterské projekty ako Wikislovník (Wiktionary), Wikiknihy (Wikibooks) a Wikisprávy (Wikinews). Jej články sú upravované dobrovoľníkmi vo wiki štýle, čo znamená, že články môže meniť v podstate hocikto. Wikipediáni presadzujú politiku „nestranný uhol pohľadu“. Podľa nej relevantné názory ľudí sú sumarizované bez ambície určiť objektívnu pravdu. Vzhľadom na to, že Wikipédia presadzuje otvorenú filozofiu, jej najväčším problémom je vandalizmus a nepresnosť. "
doc = nlp(text)

print("Noun chunks:")
for nc in doc.noun_chunks:
    print(nc)

print("\nKeywords:")
for phrase in doc._.phrases:
    print("{:.4f} {:5d}  {}".format(phrase.rank, phrase.count, phrase.text))
    print(phrase.chunks)
```